# NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 282

Tags: linux

I have this appearing on my console:

`NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 282`

This appears over and over again. Other than this, the server is functioning fine.

The message tends to go away with the `acpi=off` kernel command line option, but we need ACPI for some of our platforms.

I just need to know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search (I know that does not provide the answer per se) on the linux kernel mailing list site, but the entries found seem to indicate that it is more or less something harmless.

not sure if any entry actually applies to your case, but you can take a quick look at the search result of:

local_softirq_pending site:lkml.org